# Grafana, display pod running Time

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, dashboard

I'm trying to get the running time of a pod in Grafana with this metric:

```
kube_pod_start_time{pod="consumer-deployment-697bcc9d8-rfjfh", namespace="default"}
```

But this displays all dates from the moment the pod started until the time it terminated or the current date if it is still running.

[image]

Is there a way to make it display the duration, which in this case is 11:25 - 11:10? Is there a metric that gives the end time of the pod? I can't find any, but some say it exists.
and if it possible to get same inforamtion for specific deployment for example

```
pod1,duration:15
pod2,duration:45
```

Comment: To be precise, column Time that you see on screenshot, is time when metric was reported, not the value. Value is always the same, and corresponds to starting time of the pod.

Comment: Ah I see , I thought that's the pod tracking time

Comment: Try something like this: `last_over_time(timestamp(kube_pod_start_time{namespace="default"})[1w:]) - kube_pod_start_time{namespace="default"}`
`

Comment: I tried playing around  with the metric you provided it shows a single row with time 11:30 and  216 value

Comment: 216 in this context should mean that pod was run for 216 seconds (+/- since Prometheus scrapes data once every `scrape_interval` seconds)